# QTreeView and QDataWidgetMapper interaction

Tags: python, pyqt

So I have a QTreeView witdget connected to a model, and the same model connected to a QDataWidgetMapper object which connects to a few LineEdits. My problem is that I can't figure out how to change the QDataWidgetMapper index when I click on another item in the QTreeView...

I tried this connect:

> i = QtCore.QModelIndex()
>
> self.ui.MyQTree.clicked(i).connect(self.MyDataMapper.setCurrentIndex(i))

But it doesn't work...I get a:

> TypeError: native Qt signal is not callable

Really at the end of my rope here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot connect the result of method execution as slot, but you try.
What you need to do is:

```
self.ui.MyQTree.clicked.connect(self.MyDataMapper.setCurrentIndex)
```

and the index, that view will provide when 'clicked' fires will be transferred to slot.